# What does a friend having their status as Snooze mean?

Tags: steam

One of my friends has a status of Snooze. What does this mean?
How is it different to away or busy (apart from it not being available in the list of options)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [a moderator on the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=901906) "snooze" is a state automatically applied to users that have been away from their PC for 2 hours or more.

There are [other programs that can interface with Steam](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#Public_Data), and some of these also have the option of manually changing your status to something that is normally not possible to manually set your status to.  Therefore, you might find people in the "snooze" state even though they haven't been away that long.

Comment: From the looks of it that API is read-only. I don't see how a program could change the status of a person if there isn't some other API somewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, people have reverse engineered the protocols that the Steam client uses to talk to the Steam servers, and they can forge packets and so forth.  I don't know where this falls EULA-wise, and I'm loathe to get anyone banned, so I'm not linking to any of the tools I'm aware of.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. Got confused since you linked to a read-only API. Thought you were linking there to show what method the programs used.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as the instant messenger status "idle". If they are idle, they've been away and not active for a period of time. "Snooze" is exactly the same concept, the user has not been active on Steam for a certain period of time (as Agent states, 2 hours +)

Answer (score -3):

they are afk

Your friend is away from their computer for too long.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the accepted answer, which was posted 5 years ago?